# Feedzy Issue - WP HTTP Error: cURL error 43:

Tags: curl, rss

I use Feedzy Premium to import multiple RSS feeds to my site. All the feeds are valid. Initially, the import ran just fine. However, when I try to run updates (check for new posts), the import hasn't updated since the first run. When I tried to preview the import, I received this error:

WP HTTP Error: cURL error 43:

I had previously received a cURL error 56, but somehow that got resolved. Feedzy has investigated and did not find any errors on their end. There aren't any plugin conflicts. There isn't a conflict with my theme. I'm not a developer, so I'm honestly at a loss. Please let me know if you can offer any guidance.

I created a new import with several rss feeds (via Feedzy Premium) and selected my settings.

Once I created the new import, I used a post widget block (from my theme) to display a the imported posts on specific page. It worked. I tried several Gutentor blocks as well, just to see what looked and functioned best. It worked the same for those blocks as well.

Later, when I refreshed the page, there were no updates and images only appeared for the first few post items. I was expecting at least a few new post items, but the import continued to show the same items ever since (6.17.23).

I deactivated all of my plugins, except the Feedzy plugins. The error still persisted.

I downloaded and activated a new theme, but the error persisted.

I contacted Feedzy. They investigated, but were able to run my import on their end with no problem.

I googled information on fixing the error, and found that I needed to change my cURL version. However, I could not find a way to change it on my own.

I reached out to my web host, but they don't really offer development support and suggested I reach out to Stack Overflow.